# user profile manager with laravel7

Tags: php

With laravel7, I want to allow each user to be able to modify their profile, but I can't. With my code when the connected user wants to modify his profile there is a message telling him that he is not authorized. Which is not normal. I do not know where my error lies. Please help me!

Routes:

```
route::get('/profiles/{user}', 'ProfileController@show')->name('profiles.show');
route::get('/profiles/{user}/edit', 'ProfileController@edit')->name('profiles.edit');
route::patch('/profiles/{user}', 'ProfileController@update')->name('profiles.update');
```

My update view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header alert-primary">{{ __('Update my profile') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('profiles.update', ['user' => $user]) }}" >
                        @csrf
                        @method('PATCH')
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="firstname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Firstname') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="firstname" type="text" class="form-control @error('firstname') is-invalid @enderror" name="firstname" value="{{ old('firstname') ?? $user->firstname}}" required autocomplete="firstname" autofocus>

                                @error('firstname')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="lastname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Lastname') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="lastname" type="text" class="form-control @error('lastname') is-invalid @enderror" name="lastname" value="{{ old('lastname') ?? $user->lastname}}" required autocomplete="lastname" autofocus>

                                @error('lastname')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div> 

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="role" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Role') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="role" type="text" class="form-control @error('role') is-invalid @enderror" name="role" value="{{ old('role') ?? $user->role}}" required autocomplete="role" autofocus>

                                @error('role')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="phone" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Phone') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="phone" type="text" class="form-control @error('phone') is-invalid @enderror" name="phone" value="{{ old('phone') ?? $user->phone}}" required autocomplete="phone" autofocus>

                                @error('phone')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') ?? $user->email}}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="adress" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Adress') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="adress" type="text" class="form-control @error('adress') is-invalid @enderror" name="adress" value="{{ old('adress') ?? $user->adress}}" required autocomplete="adress" autofocus>

                                @error('adress')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="profession" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Profession') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="profession" type="text" class="form-control @error('profession') is-invalid @enderror" name="profession" value="{{ old('profession') ?? $user->profession}}" required autocomplete="profession" autofocus>

                                @error('profession')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Update') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\User;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
{ 
        $this->middleware('auth'); 
}

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(User $user)
    {
        // 
        return view ('profiles.show', compact ('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        // 
        $this->authorize('update', $user->profile); 
        return view ('profiles.edit', compact ('user')); 
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     *  @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update( User $user)
    {
            //

    $this->authorize ('update', $user->profile);
    $data = request()->validate ([ 
        'firstname'=>'required',
        'Lastname'=>'required',
        'phone' => 'required' ,
        'email' => 'required',
        'adress' => 'required',
        'profession' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required', 
    ]);
    auth()->$user->update($data);
    return redirect()->route('profiles.show', ['user'=> $user]); 

    } 

}
```

My model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 

class Profile extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = []; 


    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Have you put your routes in middleware `auth`? Otherwise you will not be able to access it. Becasue in your controller you have declared in your `__constructor()` every user should be authorized.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer! but what should i do to make it work? i am new to laravel

Answer (score 0):

Grab your Routes in `Auth` Middleware.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
   route::get('/profiles/{user}', 'ProfileController@show')->name('profiles.show');
   route::get('/profiles/{user}/edit', 'ProfileController@edit')->name('profiles.edit');
   route::patch('/profiles/{user}', 'ProfileController@update')->name('profiles.update');
});
```